# Postgraphile VS custom graphql resolver/schema in express server

Tags: graphql, express-graphql, postgraphile

I was experimenting with Postgraphile and it is a great tool to auto-generate the GraphQL API but I am still a little bit confused why should I use it. (P.S. I am not very experienced with GraphQL and PostgreSQL.)

Question 1:
Can I think of it this way? Postgraphile generates the code(query, mutation, resolvers, schema, types) for a server and these code are the code that we are going to write anyways if we are not using Postgraphile?

Question 2:
An example, a server receives a string `James` from the front end and I want to concat `Bond` to it before storing it in the db's full name column. How do I achieve this mutation? Am I going to need the `makeExtendSchemaPlugin` to merge my schema with the resolver in Postgraphile?

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: Postgraphile generates the code(query, mutation, resolvers, schema, types) for a server and these code are the code that we are going to write anyways if we are not using Postgraphile

Correct. `postgraphile` will create CRUD operations that are optimized and many other features which otherwise you would need to implement.

> Question 2: An example, a server receives a string James from the front end and I want to concat Bond to it before storing it in the db's full name column. How do I achieve this mutation?

You can create postgreSQL function and implement business logic. https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/custom-mutations/